# Graphics on Sony Vaio, Ubuntu based OS

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, sony-vaio

All right?

I have an Ubuntu based OS installed on a Sony Vaio laptop, and the thing is: it works great in general, much better than Windows (after trying Windows 10 I decided to not even continue using Windows if I can do so (privacy is a main issue, and another one is lack of control over the system (which is the normal thing for Microsoft systems as far as I know))), but there's something that is bothering me...

Take a look at this:

[notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja6CB.jpg)

The image is a pop up notification that appears with system information sometimes on the top of the screen... But as you can see the pop up has some horizontal lines on it, it's not totally smooth as I suppose it should be... Also, on Office (Writer application) I see some letter kind of blurred if I copy and paste a web page for example, on a document.

Have anyone experienced this, or know about it? Is this some kind of graphical driver stuff maybe?

Can any of you guys help out? Hope so...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I've used Ubuntu on several different laptops and desktops (though not a Sony) and I haven't seen this. Very occasionally I get poor graphics in an application window, but minimise/restore resolves this. You do seem to have a graphics problem: is it possible that you are not using the native resolution of the LCD? Also, do you see similar problems if you run the Ubuntu Live CD? If not, then it shows that Ubuntu is capable of handling the display correctly and there must be a problem with your installation, but I'm not sure how best to resolve it with the information I have so far.

Comment: Hi @AFH, firstly, thanks for your comment! So, as far as I remember, when using the live system the same thing occurred... About the resolution, I am not sure. If the OS automatically gets the native one than I am I guess. I don't remember changing it. What kind of information would be useful?

Comment: If you type `dmidecode | less` into a terminal and look for `Video`, you should find which graphics hardware you are using. In my case it is "Intel(R) Extreme Graphics 3 Controller". I searched for "Intel Graphics" in the package manager and found a number of support packages, including `i965-va-driver`, `intel-gpu-tools`, `libva1`, `libva-drm1`, `libva-glx1` and `libva-x11-1`. If your Sony has similar graphics, you should check that these modules are installed. Unfortunately, my only Sony is much too old to run Ubuntu, so I cannot run any checks myself.

Answer (score 0):

I cant say anything about your text blurring issue without an example image but for that notification toast, I am sure it is an issue with your desktop manager. The background image (9patch most likely) is stretched to cover the whole toast but it looks like it is repeating the image.
Knowing exactly which distro and shell you are using will help.